# Can't use Knife Tool to cut across specific loop side

Tags: knife-tool, loop, tools

[image]

Trying to use the Knife tool to cut a box out of these 2 edge loops. Problem being, the knife doesn't add a single cut when LMB on top of them. It does, however, work when i do the same thing on the loops that pass through all the other faces.
The face on the image is the top one. I can properly cut on the 2 side faces and the bottom face, but not on the top one.

What is happening here?

Comment: sometimes it happens to me also , it happens when your geometry is bad , or sometimes it happens on filled faces

Comment: I don't know what to say, the mesh is just a slightly flatten cube. Now it does new tricks as well, like cutting triangles by itself. Anyway...